# How to disable "AspNetFilterModule" in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. When I have lots of request on it (for example 20Krps) I can see in worker process request monitoring on IIS that a lot of requests are on "AspNetFilterModule" with "LogRequest" state.
How can I disable it!? What is it? What does it mean?!
I have disabled all loging features and removed all the modules of IIS.

---

**Update:**

I have uninstalled all logging module  and still I can see such a requests.